# Share Sheet with Peek and Pop

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, swift4

I am trying to get a share sheet to come up after and action button is tapped on the the peek and pop action item. The problem is that the share sheet is has to come up from a specified VC. In a normal VC, I would just say self. But in this case, once the action item is tapped, the vc that we would normally present the share sheet from gets dismissed. That is just how action items work with peek and pop. How do I tell the share sheet to present from the original VC or VC below it?

Here is the code for the share sheet.

```
//This is in the function createShareSheet
branchUniversalObject.showShareSheet(with: linkProperties, andShareText: "Check out this post!", from: self) { (string, bool) in
    print ("done")
}
```

and here is the code for the action item:

```
override var previewActionItems: [UIPreviewActionItem] {
    let action2 = UIPreviewAction(title: "Share", style: .default, handler: { previewAction, viewController in

        //This basically gives data to the function that has the above code for creating the share sheet.
        self.createShareSheet(self.selectedItem!)
        return [action2]
    })
```

Comment: You need to pass pass a reference to the original view controller through your peek and preview action code so that it can create the share sheet from the appropriate VC

Comment: it will always be from the same VC and there is only 1 vc it will ever come from. say for example the reference to the original vc can be set as a constant. how would it be done?

Comment: You can’t. You need the actual instance, which will be different each time

Comment: ok sounds good so how would I do that?

Comment: When you instantiate your peek vc you need to pass the current vc to it via a property.

Comment: would you be able to provide the code on how to pass the actual instance and then open the share sheet on that vc?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough code for me to give an exact solution, but basically you will need to pass your "current" view controller to the "peek" view controller so that it can use it to present the share sheet.

Something like:

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let detailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController else { return nil }

    detailVC.rootVC = self

    return detailVC
}
```

Now you can use the `rootVC` property in your `peek` action handler to present the share sheet from the right vc